# why gitlab package registry npm install from different url

Tags: gitlab

My gitlab version is `14.7.3`, and I configure package registry as follow:

```bash
npm config set "@scope:registry" http://hightop.com:9000/api/v4/projects/1234/packages/npm/
npm config set -- '//hightop.com:9000/api/v4/projects/1234/packages/npm/:_authToken' "glpat-token"
```

when I run `npm install`

```bash
npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME
npm ERR! Invalid tag name "@zhaolingli:vuepress-theme-dark": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\.npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-09T07_41_40_958Z-debug.log
PS D:\scm\temp\test1> npm i @zhaolingli/vuepress-theme-dark
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET http://192.168.5.242/api/v4/projects/1234/packages/npm/@zhaolingli/vuepress-theme-dark/-/@zhaolingli/vuepress-theme-dark-1.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  '@zhaolingli/vuepress-theme-dark@1.0.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     D:\.npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-09T07_41_45_410Z-debug.log
```

why the url from `http://hightop.com:9000` change to `http://192.168.5.242`,
`192.168.5.242` is gitlab server local address, Shouldn't it be `http://hightop.com:9000`?

Comment: [Configure the external URL for GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configure-the-external-url-for-gitlab)

Comment: According what you said, I haven't configured external url, but I can get maven package from `http://hightop.com:9000`, so `maven` and `npm` has different logic?

Comment: Well have you configured it? If not - then that's most likely your problem.
There's also the possibility of NPM returning an index of file URLs (for example, if mass storage is accessible via another API endpoint), where maven just returns a list of file names.

Try configuring your GL instance, and see if it resolves your issue :)

Comment: tks, I have configured gitlab instace url, and then the problem solved, however, gitlab document didn't mention it. tks again!